# Parsing error: '>' expected after renaming the file to ts

Tags: typescript, parsing-error

Help. I have been checking every bit of code for a long time, but I can’t understand what’s wrong here.

```js
import React from 'react'
import css from './FormsControls.module.css'
import commonCss from '../styles.module.css'
import { Field } from 'redux-form'
import cn from 'classnames'

const FormControl = ({ input, meta: { touched, error }, children, text, mainClass, noerror }) => {
  const hasError = touched && error
  return (
    <div className={cn(css.formControl, mainClass)}>
      <label htmlFor={input.name}>{text}</label>
      {children}
      {!noerror && hasError && <div className={css.error}>{error}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The problem arose after renaming the file from js to ts, as you can see this is not due to types

Comment: If you're using jsx syntax with typescript, you need to name the file with a `.tsx` extension.

Comment: JSX and typescript use angle brackets for different things; type assertions in typescript, or elements in jsx. So when trying to parse code, there are two ambiguous interpretations. The .tsx extension is the way you tell typescript "assume angle brackets mean elements".

Answer (score 1):

In short: If you want to combine JSX and Typescript, you need to use `.tsx`, not `.ts`.

JSX and Typescript are both extensions to javascript that were developed independently. As a result, their syntax has some conflicts, specifically with the meaning that angle brackets have. In JSX, angle brackets are used for elements, but in typescript they're used for type assertions. So when trying to parse a file that uses both, there isn't a clear way to tell what is what in all cases.

To solve this, typescript allows you to specify that angle brackets should be assumed to be JSX elements. The way that you do this is by the file extension. In a `.tsx` file, you can use JSX elements and the parser will never incorrectly think they are type assertions. The consequence of this is that you cannot consistently use angle bracket assertions in a `.tsx` file, so you should use `as` assertions instead.